# Identify a SMD diode used in a PFC circuit

Tags: diodes, surface-mount, power-factor-correction

I am trying to identify a SMD diode that is used in a PFC circuit on a SMPS power supply board from a Hisense 50" smart TV. The diode is connected on a IDP2301 (multi-mode PFC and LLC controller) IC. There are 3 diodes with the same markings, each connected to one of the gate driver outputs of the IC.

The markings on the diode are:
A1 (horizontal)
W6n (vertical)

I think "A1" is a "type" marking, but I am not sure which diode "A1" refers to.
The closest code I found was "A2", which relates to a 1N4148 diode (data from Vishay website and datasheets).

The length of the diode body is 2.2mm. The closest match to this is: SOD-123.

Can anyone identify this diode?

### UPDATE (19/05/23)

I found this service manual:
https://pdfcoffee.com/hisense-noblex-ea32x5000-chasis-mtk5655epdj-pdf-free.html

The service manual has a schematic with a IDP2301 IC on it. The diodes on the gate drivers (HSGD, LGD AND PFCGD) are all: **1N4148W**.

[image: SMD diode - A1 marking code]

[image: SMD diode in circuit]

Comment: If you need to replace it, just go with a 400V SOD-123 type. Should be good enough for a PFC circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a [1N4001](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810181722_Shandong-Jingdao-Microelectronics-1N4001W_C162732.pdf) type of diode (similar to M1 etc.).

I suggest you look up the datasheet for the chip and look at the typical schematic.

Answer (score 0):

Also possibly one of these:

- [BAS16H, SOD-123F](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bas16ht1-d.pdf): Diode Fast 75 V/0.215 A/0.25 W/1.25 Vf/6 ns
- [BAS240, SOD-110](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/101640/PHILIPS/BAS240.html): Schottky Barrier Diode 40 V/0.12 A/1 Vf/5 pF
- [MMSZ10T, SOD-123](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/MMSZ2V4T1_D-2316151.pdf): Zener 10 V/5 mA/20 Ω/0.5 W